# Glitch when page is looping when scrolling with auto-scroll

Tags: javascript

I am doing the auto-scroll where it will detect the mouse wheel movement up or down and it will continue scrolling on its own but when it reaches the top, the page should jump to the bottom and will continue scrolling to the top and vice versa. but when it reaches the top or bottom it is stuck and glitching.

this is my code for the loop thing

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {   
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 1) {
       $(window).scrollTop(0)
    }
    else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
        $(window).scrollTop( $(document).height() );
    }    
});
```

and this is for the auto-scroll thing.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0,
 currentpos = 0;


$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
         currentpos = window.pageYOffset + 1
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
   } else {
      // upscroll code
        currentpos = window.pageYOffset - 1
    window.scroll(0, currentpos)
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

I tried doing it on snippet, codepen or jsfiddle but it didn't work.
for reference, I am doing it here http://block-s.net/caps/

Answer (score 0):

Pls log `lastScrollTop` and `currentpos` your scroll event.

You will see your problem when it run to the bottom or the top of page that loop up and dow be cause your `if` condition `if (st > lastScrollTop)` => not clearly on this case.

Hope that help you.

Comment: I just noticed that whenever it passes the loop it will keep scrolling upwards. the problem is with the autoscrolling code `var st = $(this).scrollTop();` because once it passes a new loop it will keep on scrolling up. so `st` will always be greater than `lastScrollTop`